# Build Mosquitto (MQTT broker) on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, mqtt, mosquitto, messagebroker

I'm trying to build mosquitto from the source code (which is in the official github repository). After resolving some dependencies `make install` finishes without errors.

However, when testing `mosquitto_pub` I ran into the problem of missing `libmosquitto.so.1` which was not in `/var/lib`. I copied it from the source code folder and managed to publish a message to the HiveMQ broker. However, I cannot publish to the local broker (connection refused). I can't find the log (it's not in `/var/log`) and `mosquitto.conf` is only in the folder I downloaded from the repository.

I've already tried changing `allow_anonymous` in it and recompiling later, but the same problem remains.

When trying to check the service status, the following lines are displayed:

```
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-10-25 10:46:51 BST; 7s ago
  Process: 11395 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Main PID: 11395 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  CPU: 577us
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

I can publish and subscribe to an external broker, but I cannot do it to the local broker. Is there independence between mosquitto clients and the broker?

Comment: Rather than run the service, run mosquitto manualy on the command line that way you will get to see all the output. Where the logs go will depend on what is in the configuration file (that must be passed on the cmd line as there is no default location)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, in fact, when I ran it manually the message was published. It helped me a lot! Now I need to find out which parameters I use on the command line to set the location of the log and where I can find the mosquitto.db file. But it's already helped me a lot, thanks again.